# Using GeoServer Vector Tiles?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm novice in GeoServer/JavaScript.

My config:

Win 10 Pro x64 - Apache 2.14 - Tomcat 9 + deployed Geoserver 2.10.0

Apache Tomcat proxy

Tomcat 9 --- CORS

Geoserver --- Installed Vector Tiles plug-in ( geoserver-**2.10-SNAPSHOT**-vectortiles-plugin ) and WPS plug-in.

Trying to figure it out how to use Geoserver vector tiles so follow the instructions as written in Geoserver tutorial - http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html#publish-vector-tiles-in-geowebcache

Unfortunately, the result is a blank page with just Title "Mapbox Protobuf - vector tiles" and +/- zoom buttons ?!

What is the cause of that?

Perhaps it isn't working because Geoserver is deployed in Tomcat.

Update:

Screenshot of GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING log - http://i68.tinypic.com/waiqzm.jpg

Noticed in log that BaseURL = localhost:8080/geoserver/ ,but my Geoserver is located at localhost:82/geoserver/ (!)

Maybe that's the cause??

UPDATE #2

-- regenerate tiles just in EPSG:4326 --

GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING log

```
Request: getMap
Time = []
Filter = null
Format = application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector
Buffer = 0
SRS = EPSG:4326
ScaleMethod = null
Exceptions = SE_XML
StyleBody = null
StyleVersion = null
SldVersion = null
Filters = null
Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=polygon]]
Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@ef7f0020]
MaxFeatures = null
BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
FeatureVersion = null
Transparent = true
StyleFormat = sld
Sld = null
StyleUrl = null
SldBody = null
TilesOrigin = null
ValidateSchema = false
Interpolations = []
Height = 256
Width = 256
Tiled = false
Palette = null
Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-180.0 : -90.0, 0.0 : 90.0]
RemoteOwsURL = null
Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84",
```

DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",

```
SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 

AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
```

PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],

UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],

AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],

AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

```
FormatOptions = {}

FeatureId = null

ViewParams = null

Elevation = []

StartIndex = null

Env = {}

Angle = 0.0

RemoteOwsType = null

CQLFilter = null

Version = 1.1.1

BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/

Request = GetMap

Get = true

RequestCharset = UTF-8
```

RawKvp = {FORMAT=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector, STYLES=polygon, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, LAYERS=opengeo:countries, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=-180.0,0.0,-90.0,90.0, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/GEOSERVER_DATA/data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been closed. Number open: 0

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/GEOSERVER_DATA/data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.IndexedDbaseFileReader

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been closed. Number open: 0

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/GEOSERVER_DATA/data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile

2017-01-13 23:43:00,738 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0

2017-01-13 23:43:00,741 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -

Comment: what is in the log file? make sure you have set logging to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER and then make the request and paste the relevant part of the log into your question.

Comment: Thx for reply, I found one error : BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/

Comment: I found one error in request: getMap -> BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ but it should be BaseUrl = http://localhost:82/geoserver/

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the log - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=waiqzm&s=9

Comment: Screenshot is not the way to present log file. Please paste in relevant part as requested by iant.